# What does the field "SharedWithInternalId" mean?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

When getting fields in Sharepoint REST api, for all files it seems like the field "SharedWithInternalId" is always null. I have tried changing access and sharing settings but that only affects the "SharedWithUserId" field. So what does "SharedWithInternalId" mean and how can I make it to be not null?